# dropdown goes under body

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The problem is that language button (site body right)
that made of bootstrap v4 dropdown is somewhy shows inside div and goes under instead of on top, and I can't figure out how to spot it, even `z-index: 10000` didn't help anyhow.

page with sample http://protasov.by/contacts

button is `#pm_language`

Comment: Please add a code snippet which highlights the problem you are having.

Comment: it's best to show code so we knowwhat you've got and tried :)

Comment: I can't find `#pm_language` button..

Comment: I've never seen so much use of position relative/absolute

Answer (score 1):

Here you have to remove some `css` and add `html` code

Firstly ,remove `overflow: hidden;` from this id

```
#wb_page_heading {
  position: relative;
//  padding-left: 20px;
//  top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: 0.16rem solid get_color_transparent('gray', 0.25);
  @include material_box_shadow(0, 0.1rem, 4px, 0.25);

 // overflow: hidden; /*Remove this*/
  float: none;
}
```

And wrap the inner content in `.clearfix`

```
<header id="wb_page_heading">
    <div class="clearfix"><!--Wrap in this div-->
    <h2 class="wb-stl-heading2" ,="" style="float: left;">Контакты</h2>
    <div id="pm_language" class="dropdown show" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Language</button>
       <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
           <a class="dropdown-item active" href="#">English</a>
           <a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="#">Русский</a>
       </div>
    </div>
    </div><!--clearfix-->
 </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the solution after couple hours of experementing is
remove overflow: hidden from parental div element, and set manual height to it, that's make dropdown body appears on top of site canvas :)